# How do I detect .connect_pad_added() template = video_%u?

Tags: rust, gstreamer

Using the gstreamer Rust bindings, how can I test if a sometimes pad that has been added is from template `video_%u` or `audio_%u`?

For example, using qtdemuxm, the following pad added is called once for video and once for audio

```
.connect_pad_added(move |demux, src_pad| {
```

according to the binding docs it seems

```
get_property_name_template(&self)
```

but this fails

```
.connect_pad_added(move |demux, src_pad| {
let templateName = get_property_name_template(&src_pad);
|                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

a more manual way is to get the name then if else, but is there a more direct method?

```
println!(
        "Received new pad {}",
        src_pad.get_name()
    );
```

I have also tried matching the pad form a template

```
.connect_pad_created('video_%u', src_pad{ ....
```

but I could not find a way to match the string of the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options here:

1. You check if the pad name starts with `audio_` or `video_`. You can get the name via [`get_name()`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/gstreamer/trait.GstObjectExt.html#tymethod.get_name)
2. You get the pad template from the pad via [`get_pad_template()`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/gstreamer/trait.PadExt.html#tymethod.get_pad_template) and then check the name template via [`get_property_name_template()`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/gstreamer/struct.PadTemplate.html#method.get_property_name_template)

Ideally you would however not depend on template names (unless you explicitly work with a specific element factory, like `qtdemux` here) but instead look at the caps on the pad via [`get_current_caps()`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/gstreamer/trait.PadExt.html#tymethod.get_current_caps) and if they are not available yet get notified once they change via [`connect_notify(Some("caps"), ...)`](https://gstreamer.pages.freedesktop.org/gstreamer-rs/glib/object/trait.ObjectExt.html#tymethod.connect_notify).